# Retrieving Single unique record from multiple repeating record

Tags: sql, oracle, select, distinct

If I have the following two tables

HOTELTABLE

```
 HOTELID   HOTEL NAME
  1        PARK HOTEL
  2        PARK PLAZA
  3        HOLIDAY IN
```

ROOM TABLE

```
HOTELID    ROOMINUMBER  ROOMTYPE  FLOORNUMBER  ROOMRATE
1          111          SINGLE         1          100
1          111          DOUBLE         1          200
1          113          DOUBLE         2          200
2          111          FAMILY         2          300
```

I want to list the hotel name, room type and room rate for each hotel that contains the word `PARK` in its name, and if a room of the same type and rate at the same hotel I want to list it only once. The following is my code... Would I need a subquery, how can I go around this query?

```
SELECT DISTINCT HOTELNAME, 
       DISTINCT ROOMTYPE, 
       DISTINCT ROOMRATE
  FROM ROOM, 
       HOTEL
 WHERE HOTELNAME LIKE '%PARK%'
GROUP BY HOTEL.HOTELNAME, 
         ROOMTYPE;
```

THE OUT PUT SHOUD BE

```
HOTEL NAME      ROOMTYPE   ROOMMATE
PARK HOTEL       SINGLE     100
PARK HOTEL       DOUBLE     200
PARK PLAZA       FAMILY     300
```

Comment: what will be your output then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All items in your select must appear in the group by.

And you need to actually join the two tables together, based on the hotel id.

```
SELECT H.HOTELNAME, R.ROOMTYPE, R.ROOMRATE
FROM HOTEL H INNER JOIN ROOM R ON H,HOTELID = R.HOTELID
WHERE H.HOTELNAME LIKE '%PARK%'
GROUP BY H.HOTELNAME, R.ROOMTYPE, R.ROOMRATE
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    HOTELNAME, 
    ROOMTYPE, 
    ROOMRATE
FROM 
    ROOM 
    JOIN HOTEL
       ON ROOM.HOTEL_ID = HOTEL.HOTEL_ID
WHERE 
    HOTELNAME LIKE '%PARK%'
```